# Синоним к "тот, перед кем преклоняются, кем гордятся"

Tags: семантика, синонимы

Нужен синоним к "тот, перед кем преклоняются, кем гордятся, восхищаются, к кому испытывают глубокое уважение".
Одним словом. Не обязательно точный. Есть "высокий", "величественный" но это все очень далеко... Героический - слишком узко. Больше ничего на ум не приходит.
(+)
Вот еще хорошо бы с оттенком значения "трогательный". Но это я, наверное, слишком много хочу.

(++) пояснение 25.06.2015

Вот представьте... Как вариант. Вернулся человек с войны. Без ноги, но с орденом. Герой, нет спору. **(????)** и уважаемый. Но в жизни - беспомощный в общем-то и жалкий. При этом продолжает "воевать" с окружающими за свои идеалы... Вот как его назвать? "**(????)** и жалкий одновременно." Вместо **(????)** что вставить?

Должно быть что-то простое и понятное. Для названия. Наподобие "Блеск и нищета куртизанок".

(+)----------------------------------
31.03.2016

***Слушайте, тут по другому поводу вдруг вспомнилось слово "возвышенный". Вот примерно его я и искал тогда. Совсем если точно - что-то достаточно близкое.***

***Какие синонимы есть к слову "возвышенный"?***

Comment: Божество - пойдет?

Comment: Нет. Во-первых, нужно прилагательное, во-вторых - земное, человеческое..

Comment: Блистательный, несравненный, неподражаемый, непревзойдённый, восхитительный, изумительный, потрясающий...

Comment: Долго думал. Прилагательного, пожалуй, не знаю такого. Имя вот знаю. Ирина Роднина.
Может быть, "царственный", но трогательности тут, конечно, нет.

Comment: Я таких людей называю *избранными*, избранниками.

Comment: Нет, не совсем то... посмотрите уточнение вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Я давно забыл про этот вопрос, актуальности нет.

Я так и не нашел приемлемого синонима, написал, кажется, "достойный восхищения".

Вся фраза зазвучала как-то так:

"Он целыми днями сидел за письменным столом, постоянно что-то переписывая, зачеркивая и восстанавливая, сознавая свою физическую никчемность и социальную ненужность, и в то же время пытаясь создать что-то полезное, поделиться с людьми хоть чем-то, жалкий и достойный восхищения одновременно" (по памяти).

Сложился образ? Вроде да.

Даю только для того, чтобы вы поняли вопрос, коль на него все еще продолжают идти ответы.

Comment: Раз ни один из ответов не помечен как принятый, "Community" будет выпихивать этот вопрос в "текущие", чтобы посмотрели и ответили...  Может быть, попросить кого-то порекомендовать к закрытию?

Comment: Зачем? Что Вы выдумываете? Пускай висит. Закрывать надо вопросы вредные, неправильно сформулированные, не попадающие в формат по формулировке или тематике и т.д., а не просто неактуальные для автора. Тут таких 99.99%.

Answer (score 1):

> Вся фраза зазвучала как-то так:
>
> "Он целыми днями сидел за письменным столом, постоянно что-то переписывая, зачеркивая и восстанавливая, сознавая свою физическую никчемность и социальную ненужность, и в то же время пытаясь создать что-то полезное, поделиться с людьми хоть чем-то, жалкий и достойный восхищения одновременно" (по памяти).
>
> Сложился образ? Вроде да.

О, да. сложился. Лучше ИМХО будет "вызывающий жалость и восхищение одновременно". В слове "достойный" есть ненужная здесь обьективация, оно нейтрализует эмоцию рассказчика. Но два Щ подряд и Ж - неприятно. Что если всё-таки героический? "Жалкий и героический одновременно" ?  Так и короче, и энергичнее.

Comment: Послушайте, спасибо, конечно, но это уже проехали. Да и текст я восстанавливал по памяти. Нужно было для сиюминутной цели, не до стилистики. Нет, героического там не было.

Comment: @behemotus я просто пока любыми средствами нагоняю 50 очков. Вы сейчас добавили мне сразу 10, так что спасибо вам.

Comment: Зачем они вам? Впрочем, как скажете. Щаз усё будет.

Comment: И сделалось по слову его. Пасиб!  Ну держитесь... щас комментировать буду везде!

Comment: Ну вы это... Не злоупотребляйте. ))) В рамках приличий. )))

Comment: :)                   ...........................................

Answer (score 0):

Для случая "**уважаемый и жалкий**" подойдёт (в кругу близких людей) обращение по имени-отчеству,: Иринушка Васильевна, Витечка Иванович. Если не только в круге: Защитник, Заступник, Стена, Кремень, Оборона (какой муж ни ворона, всё жене оборона), а как определение — Славный.

Comment: Нет, не в кругу. Сосредоточьтесь - и прочтите вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

На ум пришло **чествуемый**, **почитаемый**, **превозносимый**, может что и подойдёт.

Comment: Нет, не особо... Но ничего не предложили...

Answer (score 0):

**"Нужен синоним к "тот, перед кем преклоняются, кем гордятся, восхищаются, к кому испытывают глубокое уважение"."**

Слово "кумир" как Вам?

Comment: Плохо. Уже отвечал.

Answer (score 0):

"**Заслуженный**", может быть...